# MSVC hangs on one file while compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compilation

I'm having an issue where MSVC "hangs" on the first time it tries to compile a file. Let me explain..

The first time I boot up Visual Studio in the morning, I get the latest revision of the project from our version control and I hit CTRL + SHIFT + B to compile all changes. Only in this very case, where I only *just* launched MSVC and hadn't tried to compile that project, I run into MSVC hanging on one file - and that file is consistently the same file the compiler hangs on.

It will hang for about a 30 seconds or so on that one file. But if I try to recompile after and it encounters that same file again, it will compile it in less than a second.

What is going on here?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community, in a C++11 project. It's moderately sized (around 700-800KB of code) and structured okay-ish. We're using precompiled headers and have made sure we're not doing any crazy things that might slow down compile times such as large files being included / unnecessary includes / etc.  This doesn't just happen on my machine, it happens on all of our machines.

What could be the culprit of all this?

Comment: Anti-virus software or similar?

Comment: maybe it is a huge file? maybe the time is the same after you clean?

Comment: @tobi303 The file itself is rather small. It's a single class file with a rather small interface. Also, I tried cleaning, and no, that doesn't yield a hang (clean + rebuild). I'm not sure what the reason is..

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm not running any anti-virus on any of my personal machines, and it still happens.

Comment: I guess you cannot show the contents of the file?

Comment: Can you comment out some code (e.g. the implementation of the class methods) to rule out some weird compiler bug ?

Comment: Lot of possibilities. Does the file includes a huge header, a huge number of headers, or a huge tree of headers?